# Como deserializar un JSON en C# con la siguiente estructura?

Tags: c#, json

Un web service me devuelve este JSON, el cual seteo en una variable:

```
 [{
   "PO": "",
   "Status": "S",
   "Message": "OK WO : 000144439642 has been held in KIT1",
   "Process": "HOLD (OTM_TRIGGER)",
   "Auxiliary": "000144439642",
   "TicketNumber": "251765"
 }]
```

Ya he intentado muchas formas pero no puedo deserializarlo. Necesito obtener los valores para insertar en una DB.

esto es lo que he estado probando:

```
public class Work_Order
    {
        public string Wo { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Process { get; set; }
        public string Auxiliary { get; set; }
        public string Ticket { get; set; }
    }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string json = "[{\"PO\":\"\",\"Status\":\"S\",\"Message\":\"OK WO : 000144439642 has been held in KIT1\",\"Process\":\"HOLD (OTM_TRIGGER)\",\"Auxiliary\":\"000144439642\",\"TicketNumber\":\"251765\"}]";


            Work_Order wo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Work_Order>(json);            

            /*este writeline es una prueba para validar que los datos esten seteados*/
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(wo.Wo) + " " + Convert.ToString(wo.Status) + " " + Convert.ToString(wo.Message) + " " + Convert.ToString(wo.Process) + " " + Convert.ToString(wo.Auxiliary) + " " + Convert.ToString(wo.Ticket));


            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Gracias de antemano
Saludos!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aclara que cosas probaste y porque decis que no podes deserializarlo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay 2 problemas en el código,

1. Estás tratando de deserializar un array de JSON dentro de una sola variable, cámbialo a una lista:

   ```
    var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Work_Order>>(json);
   ```
2. Algunos nombres de las propiedades no coinciden con los de tu clase, cámbialos o usa el atributo `JsonProperty` para hacerlos encajar:

   ```
   public class Work_Order
   {
       [JsonProperty("PO")]
       public string Wo { get; set; }

       // ...

       [JsonProperty("TicketNumber")]
       public string Ticket { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: Excelente muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!!!